# I want to select all date in the dynamic range in sql

Tags: sql-server

[image: I have my table valus like in image]

I want to iterate startdate value through DaysCount column
Please someone help me in writing sql server query so that i can perform the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Insufficient information was provided. Plus, you did not ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way with a recursive cte, though Sean Lange answer is definitely the preferred method.

**[HERE IS A DEMO](http://rextester.com/IOZPTC82923)**

```
declare @table table (StartDate date, DaysCount int)
insert into @table
values
('20170623',1),
('20170626',3),
('20170807',1)


declare @max date = (select max(StartDate) from @table)

;with cte as(
    select min(StartDate) as StartDate
    from @table
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,StartDate)
    from cte
    where StartDate <  @max
)


select 
    c.StartDate
from 
cte c 
inner join
@table t on 
    c.StartDate < dateadd(day,t.DaysCount,t.StartDate)
    and c.StartDate >= t.StartDate
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: not working the query check this
('20170623',1),
('20170626',3),
('20170807',1),
('20170926',4)

Comment: Your comment makes no sense, but I provided a reproducible example on the link HERE IS A DEMO in my answer. I can't see what you are doing on your end to cause a problem. http://rextester.com/IOZPTC82923

Answer (score 2):

Your question is lacking a lot of clarity but I actually understand what you want here. The best way to accomplish this is with a tally table. I keep one as a view in my system.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Now we need a table to start with to hold our data. This is something you should post in the future. Then we can simply utilize the power of our tally table and voila, the problem is simple.

```
declare @SomeTable table
(
    StartDate date
    , DaysCount int
)

insert @SomeTable
select '2017-06-23', 1 union all
select '2017-06-26', 3 union all
select '2017-08-07', 1

select MyDate = dateadd(day, t.N - 1, st.StartDate)
from @SomeTable st
join cteTally t on t.N <= st.DaysCount
order by st.StartDate
    , t.N
```

This will output:

```
2017-06-23
2017-06-26
2017-06-27
2017-06-28
2017-08-07
```

--EDIT--
I would highly recommend using a tally table like I posted as it is incredibly useful in so many situations. But sometimes that doesn't work. No problem. Here is a way you could do this inline. Notice I also made the tally table quite a bit shorter here since you don't seem to need quite so many values.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    )

select MyDate = dateadd(day, t.N - 1, st.StartDate)
from @SomeTable st
join cteTally t on t.N <= st.DaysCount
order by st.StartDate
    , t.N
```

Comment: I don't want to create any view or table
I need it on the fly

Comment: Great answer Sean, as always. +1

Comment: @NadeemZee you don't have to create the view. You can just use the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information for a definite answer, but if all you're wanting to do is to get all dates in the date column:

```
SELECT StartDates AS Dates
FROM table_name
```

Comment: I want to iterate startdate to DaysCount column value

Answer (score 0):

First create a dates table that you can join to, and then join to the table with something like:

```
[Date] BETWEEN [StartDate] AND DATEADD(day, [DaysCount], [StartDate])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are good with Cursors in sql

```
---Creating records
with cte as(Select Cast('01-01-2000' as Date) as startDate,1 as countD
union all
Select Cast('02-01-2000' as Date) as startDate,3 as countD
union all
Select Cast('10-01-2000' as Date) as startDate,1 as countD) 
Select * into #Temp from cte;

--Creating temp table to hold results
create table #Result(
startDate Date,
)

--Using cursor to insert records
DECLARE  @startDate Date,
@count int;


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT startDate , countD
FROM #Temp

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @startDate , @count  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    WHILE @count> 0
        BEGIN
        set @count = @count-1;
        set @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, @count, cast (@startDate as date));
        INSERT INTO #Result 
        Select @startDate;

        END

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @startDate , @count   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

Select * from #Result
```